# Not allowed page to open in other tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, browser

We have 1 page and we are doing some calculation of data which takes about 20 min. If I open a new tab and try to explore the site whilst the calculation is running, I am unable to access the application and the new tab is stuck loading the page till the first tab process gets completed.

We are using MVC4 and it is an ajax call, the code of which is below.

**Why it is preventing me from accessing the application in another tab when the calculation is running?**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Administration/Recalculate',
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    cache: false,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (entityObj) {
        HideProgress("spinnerForInflationIndex");
        $("#spinnerForInflationIndex").hide();
        alert("Recalculation of Inflation Index has been done successfully, please check the log file. You may be redirected to the Login page due to session time out.");
    },
    error: function (response, status, error) {
        HideProgress("spinnerForInflationIndex");
        $("#spinnerForInflationIndex").hide();
        //Display error message
        DisplayErrorMessage(response, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Question is it should allow to access the page/application on other tab.

Comment: That's a statement. What's you're question? Is your question _should it_ do that? Is your question _how to let it_ do that?

Comment: Yes it should do that - Why it is preventing to access the application on other tab if the calculation is running.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your question to actually add in your question, and to do some writing corrections. Please check it's still accurate to your intent and makes sense.

Comment: Kindly post all code required to reproduce the problem, including server-side model/controller code.

Comment: Can you set {async : true} and try? By default it is true but if in your code you did jQuey Ajax Option initialization then it may have changed to false.

Comment: Hi10 I have tried but no luck

Comment: There will be ShowProgress as you have HideProgress("spinnerForInflationIndex"); in success and error, can you check with it? Comment such progress indicator and make just Ajax call.

Comment: Nop that i have already tried...